# Can we assign more memory to the Spark APP than cluster it self?

Tags: apache-spark

Say the spark cluster is a stand alone cluster.
Master having 1GB memory and slave having 1GB memory.

When you submit a application to the cluster, you can specify how much memory the driver program and worker program can have. So is it possible that to specify some higher value like 10Gb to driver and 10Gb to worker?

I mean what will happen if the program you submitted is requiring more memory than the cluster it self. (Let us assume that the physical computer is having enough memory)

Answer (score 0):

Spark has a feature called "Dynamic Allocation". It can be turned on using

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = true
```

More details here
http://www.slideshare.net/databricks/dynamic-allocation-in-spark

Answer (score 0):

If you request more memory than the resource manager has access to, you will not be allocated all of your workers. The resource manager will allocate as many as it can, and if at least 1 worker is allocated, your program will be able to run (at least on YARN). Your resource manager will not allocate a worker (or the driver) with less memory than is requested. There is no such thing as a partial worker.